# $3$-dimensional shape

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, graphing-functions

What $3$-dimensional shape is represented by graph of the set of pints $ (rcos\theta, rsin\theta,z)$ where $r$ is a constant real value, $\theta$ range from $0$ to $2\pi$ radiant and $z$ range over the real number.

I was thinking that the graph might be a cylindrical polar coordinate system, but when I tried to use a graphing app it seems like Elliptic cone. Would someone explain to me and show me a graph of it.

Comment: what app are you using ? this is cylinder : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html

Comment: http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/tools/parsur/

Comment: notice. you use there $(t*cos(\theta), t*sin(\theta), t)$... so $t$ is on the first 2 terms is not good for you. try to set $r=1$ for example and graph: $(cos(\theta), sin(\theta), t)$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me ! So, what is the different in shape between $(cos\theta,sin\theta, z)$ , where $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $z$ ranges over the real number. And $(r*cos\theta,r*sin \theta, z)$ where $r$ is constant and where $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $z$ ranges over the real number.

Answer (score 1):

These are cylindrical coordinates. Look it up!

Notice that if we set $z=c=constant$, these coordinates define a circumference of radius $r$ at height $z=c$. Now take this circumference and change $z$ from $c$ to any other point of the $z$-axis. This defines a cylinder.

I suspect that what you did to obtain an elliptic cone was to take the position vector in this coordinate system $\mathbf{x}=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)$ and change the angle $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. Of course, for a given $r$, this defines a cone, but you forgot that there is another variable, $z$, which may change as well, effectively defining a cylinder.

Comment: what is the different in shape between (cosθ,sinθ,z) , where θ ranges from 0 to 2π and z ranges over the real number. And (r∗cosθ,r∗sinθ,z) where r is constant and where θ ranges from 0 to 2π and z ranges over the real number

Comment: Since $r$ is the radius of the cylinder, a larger $r$ makes a thicker cylinder. Notice that $r$ multiplies $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$, which are functions ranging from -1 to 1. Then, introducing the factor $r$, $r\sin\theta$ and $r\cos\theta$ will range from $-r$ to $r$. You have to understand that the $r$ we are talking about is constant, so there is no conceptual difference between arbitrary $r$ and $r=1$, which defines the cylinder of radius 1.

Comment: Well done ! thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If you fix $z$ to equal some real number $C$, notice that you restrict the image to the plane $z = C.$

Then, what is the image of the set of points when this $z$ is fixed? i.e., what does $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, C)$ look like when $\theta$ ranges between $0$ and $2\pi$?

Comment: I believe it should look like a unit circle ?

Comment: Not a unit circle, rather a circle of radius $r$, centered $(0, 0, C)$. So, as you range $C$ over the real numbers, what does that become then?

Comment: it will look a cylinder ?

Comment: That's correct.